# Silverlight DataGridColumn AttachedProperties

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid, attached-properties, datagridcolumn

I am attempting to create an `AttachedProperty` for a `DataGridColumn` within Silverlight 3.0 and I am having some issues.

Here is the AttachedProperty:

```
public class DataGridColumnHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Header", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridColumnHelper),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnHeaderPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnHeaderPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string header = GetHeader(d);

        var dataGridColumn = d as DataGridColumn;

        if (dataGridColumn == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        dataGridColumn.Header = GetHeader(dataGridColumn);
    }

    public static string GetHeader(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeader(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

}
```

As you can see it is really simple, I am trying to overcome the limitation that the Header Property in the DataGridColumn class cannot be bound.

This XAML works as expected...

```
<Controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OwnerName}"                                                                         
                         HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"

                         Behaviors:DataGridColumnHelper.Header="User Name"/>
```

However this XAML throws an error...(Specifically: {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: AG_E_PARSER_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND [Line: 224 Position: 112]
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   ....})

```
<Controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OwnerName}"                                                                         
                         HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"

                         Behaviors:DataGridColumnHelper.Header="{Binding Resources.UserNameListViewHeading, Source={StaticResource Labels}}"/>
```

Just for experimentation I attached this property (with the binding syntax above) to a `DataGrid` and checked the `DataGridColumnHelper.Header` property in the `OnHeaderPropertyChanged` method and the value was correct (and an exception wasn't thrown)

It is my understanding that the object that the AttachedProperty is attached to must be a `DependencyProperty`.  Looking through Reflector, `DataGridColumn` (from which `DataGridTextColumn` derives) derives from `DependencyProperty`.

Can somebody please shed some light on this?  I am trying to Localize our application, and I am having trouble with the DataGrid.  I am sure I can do this in code-behind, but I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, the problem is very simple, this won't work because the DataGridTextColumn is "detached" from the Visual Tree. Your DataGridTextColumn object is rooted in the Columns collection of the DataGrid - see the indirection. So even attached properties will not work as you expect. Now there is a way to make all this work using something I'm calling Attached Bindings, see:

http://www.orktane.com/Blog/post/2009/09/29/Introducing-nRouteToolkit-for-Silverlight-(Part-I).aspx

Just remember to attach the binding properties using something that is in the VisualTree (so the Grid holding the column would do just fine.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have been following your posts on the nRoute Toolkit, and am looking forward to experimenting with it.  Thanks for the descriptive answer.

Comment: What about for Run in Silverlight? Attached property with binding on Run doesn't work in SIlverlight...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, im assuming UserName is a property in your viewmodel

```
    <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OwnerName}"                                                                         
HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
Behaviors:DataGridColumnHelper.Header="{Binding UserName}"/>
```

I cant test your scenario so my post is just an idea. Might work, might not.

Comment: The Binding I am attempting to use is from a Resource File, because we are localizing our strings.  The binding of a DataGridTextColumn is based off the Items source (assuming we don't specify a source as I did in the above example), therefore the DataContext is not the same as the DataGrid.  Thanks